# form data not sent to view as post

Tags: django, forms, post, get, action

Hi I have a two forms on my home page, a `contact us' form and a 'drop down form to change the language of the site. since both forms are going to be in the base template i figure i must find a way to send the content of the forms to specific views to process the submission. Currently my site is a single page site so i dont have a problem with the contact form

Contact Form is

```
<form method="post" action="" role="form" id="footer-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.name.label }}">{{ form.name.label }}</label>
    {{ form.name }}
    <p class="help-block danger">{{ form.name.errors }}</p>
    <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.email.label }}">{{ form.email.label }}</label>
    {{ form.email }}
    <p class="help-block danger">{{ form.email.errors }}</p>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="sr-only" for="{{ form.message.label }}">{{ form.message.label }}</label>
    {{ form.message }}
    <p class="help-block danger">{{ form.message.errors }}</p>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

And the language form is

```
<form action="/setlang" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="/"/>
<select name="language">
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{ language.code }}"
{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}
selected="selected"{% endif %}>
{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

View that renders page

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    # send_email(['elraphah@gmail.com'],'YonniQ','info@verdin.no',"Testing","Thanks for the Test" )

    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        print 'Form Validation '
        print form.is_valid()
        if form.is_valid():
            send_email(['info@verdin.no'], request.POST['name'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['message'])

    return render_to_response('home.html',locals())
```

Due to some issues i was having with django's i18n's set_language view i decided to create my own hence `setlang` in my form action. 
When i make the action attrib empty like in the contact form, and submit, the form submits to my home view and the queryDict contains the form fields and values but when i attempt to submit to another view, in this case through `/setlang` url the form does not post, i only get and empty queryDict. I dont know why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using url tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url), you must have two urls defined in your urls.py, so in each action form attribute place the correct view name using tag, something like:

For contact form:

```
action={% url 'home' %} # url(r'^/$', views.home, name='home')
```

For setlang form:

```
action={% url 'setlang' %} # url(r'^/setlang$', views.set_lang, name='setlang')
```

Then in each function view you can filter the request by post method, as you did in home view.

Hope it can help.